# DateTime now converting Datetime string to specified format

Tags: c#, datetime

So i require the the string format of the current date to be converted to a datetime for my console app program but it is returning the wrong format, i am using the ParseExact for this e.g

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"); // 2018-06-13 11:10:07.949
var todayDate = DateTime.ParseExact(currentDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 13/06/2018 11:10:07
```

i commented what the output i receive.

My question is: Why is it being converted other than the way i specified?

Comment: what is the question?!

Comment: do you want to get `DateTime` as a string in the format in the first line?

Comment: @styx yes but i dont understand why it is being converted other than the way i specified, that would be my question, sorry should have clarified a bit more

Comment: @Ashraf96 `DateTime` objects doesn't have format.

Comment: @Ashraf96 why you are converting from `DateTime` to `string` and then back again?

Comment: @styx so basically i require the Datetime to be at a format i specified but it returns a string value and i need it to be a Datetime so i can compere dates from a sql server for example that use a certain date format.

Comment: @Ashraf96  `DateTime` format is not  relevant when comparing

Answer (score 1):

With ParseExact, you are giving information about what is input datetime format. If you want to format it for output, you're going to do that in `ToString` method, like you did in first row.
So, your code does this:

`currentDate` will be string in given format

`todayDate` will be `DateTime` object.
If you want `todayDate` to output in given format,  you should do:

```
todayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

To output current datetime, it's enough to do

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

DateTime object will always be DateTime, you can only set output format for it, and C# will always know how to deal with DateTime as an object.
In your current code, you're needlessly creating string, to convert to DateTime, to convert to string again...

Comment: i understand that but this returns a string value. i need this exact format but as a DateTime. that was what i was confused with, i wasn't sure why ParseExact didnt do this.

Comment: SQL knows how to deal with DateTime that is written as a string, as long s you put it between single quotes

Comment: Other way is to do `SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@dt",                 System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
            parameter.Value = DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` objects does not have format, and format argument inside `ParseExact()` method is a format specifier that defines the required format of your date string.

From MSDN:

> **DateTime values and their string representations**
>
> Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. The actual DateTime value is independent of the way in which that value appears when displayed in a user interface element or when written to a file. **The appearance of a DateTime value is the result of a formatting operation. Formatting is the process of converting a value to its string representation**.

References: **[DateTime Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**, **[DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**

Answer (score 0):

Try Piping your date (stored in a variable) like this in your html code

```
<span>{{MyDate| date:"dd MMM yy hh:mm a"}}</span>
```

Comment: I think you missed the language mate

Comment: Ohh.. yeah, so it seems

Answer (score 0):

Your todayDate variable is DateTime. 
So it contains year:2018, month:06, day:13 and so on. Your editor prefers (**depends on your computer's or editor's culture**) to show that DateTime variable as 13/06/2018 11:10:07. But it does not matter about its original value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `DateTime` doesn't have any format but date and time only. You have two options

Specify the format explicitly:

```
  Console.Write(todayDate.ToString(ci, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Specify the format globaly (the thing you are probably looking for)

```
  // Current culture 
  CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

  // ... With specified DateTime format
  ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
  ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.fff";

  // Now we have current culture with changed DateTimeFormat 
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;

  Console.Write(todayDate);
```

Now on `Console.Write(todayDate)` .Net will do `.ToString()` with `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which in turn apply the format specified.